# Common practice for resource-specific OAuth2 grants?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Looking at the authorization code flow of OAuth 2.....

Suppose a user has several resource (e.g. accounts, repositories).

**How should the client specify which resource it's asking for permissions to?**

Of course, it could always be left up to the user to choose which resource, but that can confusing, and the user could choose the wrong one. And you could also just grant access to *all* resources, but that's overly broad in this case.

How can the client inform which resource it is requesting access to?

For example,

```
https://example.com/oauth/authorize?account_id=123
```

Is there a best/common practice for this?

---

EDIT: Consider a git hosting service.

The user has access to repo-a and repo-b.

A client wants to request to access to repo-a.

How should the OAuth be structured to allow the client to request access to repo-a? (The user would reject a request to access repo-b.)

Answer (score 0):

**OVERVIEW**

It is not common in OAuth to ask a user to grant access to an individual resource and you usually categorize instead, which enables resources to grow:

- Ask the user to consent to read access to all repos
- Ask the user to consent to read access to all repos for mobile apps
- Ask the user to consent to read access to all Typescript repos

**SCOPES**

The client sends scopes based on areas of data, and what can be done with that data:

```
authorize?scope='openid profile repo mobile'
```

The result of authorization would be that an access token is sent to APIs, which might include the following scopes:

```json
{
"subject": 6789245,
"scope": "openid profile repo mobile"
}
```

- If someone tried to use the access token to get details on repo B (not a mobile repo), then the API's authorization checks would prevent this, which is authorization based on scopes.

**CLAIMS**

Whenever you want to authorize dynamically you use claims. If you were building your own system you could potentially customize token issuance to add specific repos to the access token, based on whatever business logic made sense to you:

```json
{
"subject": 6789245,
"scope": "openid profile repo mobile"
"repos": ["A", "C"],
}
```

- If someone tried to use the access token to get details on repo B, the API's authorization checks would prevent this, which is authorization based on claims.

**DATA ACCESS**

You wouldn't usually include individual resource IDs in the token like this however, and instead they would be managed by your API, which would exclude repo B in its data access:

```
select * from repo where type='mobile' and subject=6789245
```

- If someone tried to use the access token to get details on repo B, the API's authorization checks would prevent this, since it would not be found in the filter criteria. Note that this also uses claims, to ensure that only the data owner can get the repo.

**GIT SPECIFICS**

Of course, if you are using someone else's system you will be limited to the authorization options it supports, such as [GitHub Scopes](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps), and these may not do what you want. You may therefore need to prompt for access all repos, if it is not possible to limit access in the desired way.

**FURTHER INFO**

For further info on designing access to resources using OAuth, see these Curity articles:

- [Scope Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/)
- [Claims Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/)

The scopes article mentions `Prefix Scopes` to get a runtime scope that maps to a particular ID, such as `transaction-1234`. That is quite an advanced topic and would not usually be used in a Git repo scenario - but this pattern is used in Open Banking.

Comment: I'm trying to decipher the answer here...... Take a git hosting service. The user has access to repo-a and repo-b. A client wants to request to access to repo-a. (The user would reject a request to access repo-b.) How should the OAuth be structured to allow the client to request access to repo-a?

Comment: My answer was a little confusing so I updated it based on the most common OAuth design patterns - hope it is clearer now.